# Alljoyn compilation fails on rpi with ubuntu mate

Tags: ubuntu, alljoyn, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to compile alljoyn on a Raspberry Pi 3 model B running Ubuntu mate following these instructions:
http://blog.rajenki.com/2015/05/alljoyn-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian-and-windows-10/

When I run the first scons command I get the following error:

```
scons: Building targets ...
    [CXX]     alljoyn_core/router/test/advtunnel.cc
In file included from /usr/include/endian.h:60:0,
                 from /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/pthreadtypes.h:21,
                 from /usr/include/signal.h:361,
                 from alljoyn_core/router/test/advtunnel.cc:22:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/byteswap.h: In function 'unsigned int __bswap_32(unsigned int)':
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/byteswap.h:44:31: sorry, unimplemented: Thumb-1 hard-float VFP ABI
 __bswap_32 (unsigned int __bsx)
                               ^
scons: *** [build/linux/arm/debug/obj/alljoyn_core/router/test/advtunnel.o] Error 1
```

I have looked around, but have not been able to findhow to fix this error.  The instructions worked fine on Raspberian which leads me to believe it is a distro problem, but I am not sure what in particular. Can anyone tell me what causes/how to fix this error?

Edit: add build command

```
scons OS=linux CPU=arm WS=off OE_BASE=/usr BR=on BINDINGS=cpp CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you are building thumb code. Is this the native compiler or a cross compiler?

Comment: Cross compiler, as the instructions said to use. Added the command to the question.